# How to create vertical tab with js as paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I want to create something like this menu using bootstrap. But I can't do this. I am creating but there are lots of problem. Is there anyone who can solve this prob? **Must remember I am doing with bootstrap 4**. Here is the demo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                        <strong>Home tab </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur corporis,
                        culpa delectus deleniti dolorem exercitationem facilis hic, incidunt nemo nulla officia qui repudiandae,
                        sed voluptates. Commodi maxime possimus sed!
                    </div>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab"><strong>
                            Profile tab </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur corporis,
                        culpa delectus deleniti dolorem exercitationem facilis hic, incidunt nemo nulla officia qui repudiandae,
                        sed voluptates. Commodi maxime possimus sed!
                    </div>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
                        <strong>Message tab </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur corporis,
                        culpa delectus deleniti dolorem exercitationem facilis hic, incidunt nemo nulla officia qui repudiandae,
                        sed voluptates. Commodi maxime possimus sed!
                    </div>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
                        <strong>Setting tab </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur corporis,
                        culpa delectus deleniti dolorem exercitationem facilis hic, incidunt nemo nulla officia qui repudiandae,
                        sed voluptates. Commodi maxime possimus sed!
                    </div>
                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In this menu. Need a header and under the header need to show details with same background color.**

**Thank you** 
[image: Menu]

Comment: One more thing put the js files in the end of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Bootstrap's **Collapse - Accordion**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Theory & Concepts
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul>
          <li>Images Files Formats</li>
          <li>Pixels vs Vector</li>
          <li>...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Adobe Illustrator CC
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul>
          <li>Point1</li>
          <li>Point2</li>
          <li>PointN</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Outsourcing/Freelancing
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul>
          <li>Point1</li>
          <li>Point2</li>
          <li>PointN</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for collapse in bootstrap, check this tutorial [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/)
Here is a sample code for your problem

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Theory & Concepts
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <li>Image file formats</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Adobe Illustrator CC
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
      //For Adobe illustrator CC
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            OutSourcing/freelancing
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
      //For outsourcing and freelancing
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```